# Can anybody help me resolve the syntax?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, specifications, criteria-api

if anybody can explain how this api work or take the paramaters when u search for  a product . how this product status ,category id reflects .

seproduct/api/products?status.equals=Published&categoryId.in=59&name.contains=protein%20123&foodTypeId.in=1&allergenId.in=2&page=1&size=20&sort=sellingPrice,DESC

Comment: You need to improve your format and details of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I can just guess because you don't provide the code or any documentation of the API.

This is the path:

```
seproduct/api/products?
```

Parameters

`.equals` and `.in` would translate to `=` and `IN` in SQL select.

`contains` probably to `like '%<keywords>%'`

```
status.equals=Published
categoryId.in=59
name.contains=protein%20123
foodTypeId.in=1
allergenId.in=2
```

Page and size are used for pagination and sort for sorting (DESC = descending)

```
page=1
size=20
sort=sellingPrice,DESC
```

Comment: can you explain me how this informayion was sent from backedn to fronted i dont understand the flow.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. I assume that the result of this request is a JSON structure

Comment: Can anybody explain how this api works or takes the paramaters when you search for a product. How this product status ,category id reflects .

seproduct/api/products?status.equals=Published&categoryId.in=59&name.contains=protein%20123&foodTypeId.in=1&allergenId.in=2&page=1&size=20&sort=sellingPrice,DESC

Comment: That's what I explained

Comment: how does all this field take value from using the specification and criteria api, can you help me with that

Comment: can u similarly explain me for grater than and less than equal to ,also can i use In and like together in  postman